Starvation Condition versus Deadlock in the critical section problem
I'm reading Ben-Ari's book Principles of Concurrent and Distributed Programming and am getting a little confused by his presentation of the "Starvation" requirement and the "Deadlock" requirement. The definitions listed in the book are as follows: 
Freedom from deadlock: If some processes are trying to enter their critical sections, then one of them must eventually succeed. 
Freedom from (individual) starvation: If any process tries to enter its critical section, then that process must eventually succeed.  
The book then goes on to describe a couple different approaches to solving the critical section problem(for two processes only), in order to build an intuition for Dekker's algorithm. I'm getting really confused on the last two attempts though.
This is the third attempt:
So, we can clearly see that an issue here is if both processes try to enter the critical section. We end up getting stuck in the state (p3, q3, true, true). The book classifies this as Deadlock, because no thread enters the thread. So, from my understanding at this point, starvation is a stronger condition than deadlocks(like having a deadlock implies starvation, but not vice versa). But then, the book presents the next attempt. At this point, I see that there is another case of what I perceive to be deadlock. Both processes can get "stuck" in the while loops if the move together(like (p3, q3) -> (p3, q4) -> (p4, q4) -> (p4, q5) -> (p5, q5) -> (p5, q3) -> p3, q3)). But the book goes on to claim that there is actually no deadlock present in this example, but this is rather starvation. Why is this so? What marks the distinction between starvation and deadlock in this case? From my understanding, both processes are trying to enter the critical section, but it is not the case that eventually one of them is successful. I would understand if it was deadlock and starvation, but I'm not understanding why it isn't deadlock in this case. Let me know if you need any clarification on something. Thanks!
